# Is this grammatically correct? “We were thinking of holding a meeting...”

Tags: grammaticality

The following sentence seems incorrect to me, but I am not entirely certain:

> We were thinking of holding a meeting next Tuesday.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.

Although using the phrasal *thinking of* may be somewhat less formal than an infinitive *planning to*, it is not ungrammatical to do so.

A very basic mapping of the sentence is as follows:

```
We - were thinking of - holding a meeting next Tuesday.
Sub    Verb Phrase         Object (Gerund Phrase)
```

Others may not consider *thinking of* as phrasal, and consider the second half of the sentence as a prepositional phrase. This is still allowable since gerund phrases function as nouns

```
We - were thinking - of (holding a meeting next Tuesday).
Sub   Verb Phrase    Prep + Noun Phrase (Gerund Phrase)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is correct. There is nothing wrong with its grammar.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing facts, references, or specific expertise which support it.